# Copy contents of a unique pointer array in the copy constructor

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

My class contains a unique pointer to an array. When the copy constructor is called, I want the class to create its own unique pointer array and just copy the contents of the old unique pointer array. I keep getting errors about converting from a const value, and I'm not sure how to get around it.

My pointer is declared under private like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Manager[]> managers;
```

I planned to just loop through the array and copy manually, so I made this copy constructor:

```
Restaurant::Restaurant(const Restaurant &_r)
{
    Manager *_managers = _r.managers;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MANAGERS; i++)
    {
        managers.get()[i] = _managers[i];
    }
}
```

It gives the const convert error on this line:

```
Manager *_managers = _r.managers;
```

I just want to make a deep copy. How can I go about it to make this work?

Comment: Isn't `_r.managers` a unique_ptr? You can't assign it to something else.

Comment: Also, why the unique_ptr if you want copy semantics? Wouldn't an `std::vector<Manager>` be better suited?

Comment: he want just each class instance to have a unique_ptr to some array. Does usage of unique_ptr in a class imply a copy prohibition? If the object pointed to is indeed unique, then he don't want to make it shared_ptr, but still he want to copy class instances.

Comment: @piotruś: With `unique_ptr` you have to do the copy manually, which means writing a copy constructor and copy assignment. `vector` has one built-in, so you don't have to write either of those.

Comment: of course appropriate copy constructor and assignment operators are needed in such case, this is what he does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that it won't compile is that
 `_r.managers` is of type `std::unique_ptr<Manager[]>`, but you want to initialize a raw pointer with this.

just change it to:

```
Restaurant::Restaurant(const Restaurant &_r)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MANAGERS; i++)
    {
        managers.get()[i] = _r.managers.get()[i];
    }
}
```

or first take a smart pointer's data (which is an array)

```
Manager *_managers = _r.managers.get();
```

and then you can use it as was before:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MANAGERS; i++) {
        managers.get()[i] = _managers[i];
}
```

Comment: This got it to compile, but the application crashes at the assignment. I printed out the values to verify that _r is there, but they crash upon assignment attempt.

Comment: probably your array is not initialized. check this, and write also assignment operator for your class Restaurant. This is necessary. At the moment it might be just: Restaurant& operator=(const Restaurant &_r)
{
    if ( &_r != this) { for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MANAGERS; i++)
    {
        managers.get()[i] = _r.managers.get()[i];
    } } return *this;
}

Comment: Yes, I forgot to initialize the array and I forgot to initialize the unique pointer in the class being copied to. I have it working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the line giving you an error, `managers` is an `std::unique_ptr<Manager[]>`. You're trying to assign it to a `Manager*`, which won't work.

You can fix it by taking the raw pointer of of the `unique_ptr`, for example:

```
Manager *_managers = _r.managers.get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy the content of unique_ptr<>, you might want to use "deep copy", this means that you write `copy constructor` in class `Manager` and a clone function.
Example for copy constructor:

```
Manager(Manager const& manager) {
  name = manager.name;
  title = manager.title;
}
```

clone function:

```
unique_ptr<Manager> clone() const {
  return make_unique<Manager>(*this);
}
```